# TypeError: jQuery(...).ready(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

OK, I know this has been asked before but none of the answers seems to apply to my case. I'm trying to get a very tiny piece of jQuery running (I'm just getting started on it).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.comtrig').on('click',function(){
        $(this).next().animate({'display':'inline'},1000);
    });
})();
```

I get the error `TypeError: jQuery(...).ready(...) is not a function` in FF or `Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function` in Chrome.

- Solution 1 was to replace `$` with `jQuery` but I obviously already did that as shown above
- I'm not in Wordpress either
- I'm using only jQuery and the above mini script, no other JS
- jQuery itself seems to load fine
  [image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: What happens if you type $ or jQuery into console in browser?

Comment: Just to be sure, are you loading jQuery *before* your `jQuery(...).ready(...)` call?

Comment: what is the order of jquery file including?

Comment: I think there is a typo `})();`

Comment: The `<script>` for jQuery comes right before the `<script>` tag for the mini script. I'm not sure whether that guarantees it also loads first since the second script is (way) smaller and locally stored.

Comment: Replace `})();` with `});`, This is incorrect `{())`

Comment: Encountered this when integrating anythingSlider in MVC 4. The script goes: $(function () {        $('#slider').anythingSlider();    }); Checked anythingslider.js and it has a closure. Even added the script in Bundle.Config. The downloaded sample does not return Type Error. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

try to remove this `();` at the end of doc ready:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('.comtrig').on('click',function(){
    $(this).next().animate({'display':'inline'},1000);
  });
}); //<----remove the (); from here
```

`();` is normally used to have a *Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)* which has some kind of syntax like this:

```
(function(){
   // your stuff here
})(); //<----this invokes the function immediately.
```

---

Your errors:

in firefox = `TypeError: jQuery(...).ready(...) is not a function`

in chrome = `Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function`

because:

Your document ready handler is not a **Self-executing anonymous function**.

Comment: @Jai: I see! `()` is included for a SIAF and the `$(document).ready` syntax is NOT a SIAF. Thanks, that's a helpful disambiguation you wrote.

Comment: @RubenGeert When you call `.ready(function() { ... })`, you are calling `ready()` and passing an anonymous function as a parameter. When you call `.ready(function() {...})()`, you are doing the same as the above, but then trying to execute the result of `ready()` as a function. `.ready()` returns a jquery object, which is not a function.

Comment: @RubenGeert see _Self-executing anonymous function_ or _Immediately-Invoked Function Expression_ used to have some special syntax to do this, while jQuery is desined and developed that way, so there is no need to do this in your case, although you can make a closure to save your `$` alias to jQuery for use in your closure if you have used multiple libraries which uses the `$`.

Comment: @downvoter why downvote after 12 upvotes. i guess it really needs a comment for that right.

Comment: @downvoter well i get a second downvote i don't know why?

Answer (score 8):

There are two issues in the code.

1 - The brackets at the end of the code.

2 - $(this) should have been jQuery(this) or $ inside function.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.comtrig').on('click',function(){
        $(this).next().animate({'display':'inline'},1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: But you completely failed to explain WHAT you changed, and WHY you changed it. Maybe if you'd explained, people would have taken a moment to understand...

Comment: I completely agree with @NiettheDarkAbsol, Yours is first correct answer, but without explanation

Answer (score 3):

Remove the extra brackets `()` at the end. Keep the code as below.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.comtrig').on('click',function(){
        $(this).next().animate({'display':'inline'},1000);
    });
}); // <== remove () from here
```

Answer (score 1):

Passing jquery object this way works for me.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("jquery");
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 0):

These Errors:

```
    TypeError: jQuery(...).ready(...) is not a function
    or
    Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function
```

are also happens if you implement Jquery library after your code, it should be before, **ORDER MATTER here**.

```
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js")"></script>
```