# Failed to execute 'scroll' on 'Window': 2 arguments required, but only 1 present

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code from [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ayGwn/1191/), but it gives me a error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'scroll' on 'Window': 2 arguments required, but only 1 present.
```

I have jQuery 1.8.3 installed, and script is on bottom of page. Code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(window).scroll(function() {    
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll >= 150) {
            $(".navigation").addClass("darkHeader");
        } else {
            $(".navigation").removeClass("darkHeader");
        }
    });
    </script>
```

Any help? On jsfiddle everything working. Code is on IPBoard 3.4.8.

Comment: `On jsfiddle everything working.` So your issue comes from somewhere else we aren't aware of. I guess `$` isn't refering to jQuery on your site, check it or try using `jQuery(window).scroll(...);` and replace `$` by `jQuery` inside handler

Comment: As a side note, maybe you are overwritting jQuery scroll method, try using instead `$(window).on('scroll', function(){...});` and btw, don't forget to include jQuery before calling your snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
  $(document).ready(function(){ 

   }
```

to get element after document ready

here the demo

Click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/y1z89wzs)!

update demo for notice the change of scroll

Click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/y1z89wzs/2)!

Comment: `window` object is available before the DOM is ready, this is not usefull here to use document pseudo ready event

Comment: iam not talk about window see my answer i talk about elements 

 $(".navigation")  

also i write in my answer use

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){ 

   }
to get element after document ready

Comment: But that's nothing to do with error message and btw usually browser won't let you scroll window before the DOM is ready. And your jsFiddle, with js not wrapped and put in HEAD and without ready handler works the same, not sure what should i see there. See: http://jsfiddle.net/y1z89wzs/3/

Comment: actually i dont notice any error just the element maby didnt load
so i make to him demo

Comment: did u load jquery library ?

Comment: also check this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21755397/typeerror-jquery-ready-is-not-a-function