# My play-button won't work properly

Tags: jquery, html5-video

I use the following code:

```
<video class="video-presentation">
  <source src="media/presentation.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
<div class="playpause"></div>
```

I use the following jQuery:

```
$('.video-presentation').parent().click(function () {
    if($(this).children(".video-presentation").get(0).paused){
        $(this).children(".video-presentation").get(0).play();
        $(this).children(".playpause").fadeOut();
    }else{
        $(this).children(".video-presentation").get(0).pause();
        $(this).children(".playpause").fadeIn();
    }
});
```

Everything worked fine when I tried it out in a separate file, however, when I add it to my site it suddenly doesn't work at all... You can see the code in action at my site www.scandinavija.com on the 3 page (scroll down).

Any ideas why the script won't work?

Answer (score 0):

If you open up your browsers developer tools when visiting your site, you will find the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).ready(...) is not a function
```

See this answer:
[TypeError: jQuery(...).ready(...) is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21755397/typeerror-jquery-ready-is-not-a-function)

Comment: I know, I just left it untouched for the moment. It's not a part of the problem, even if I remove it the problem is still there...